# How to print line number in CIL liveness analysis output

Tags: ocaml

Is there a way to add line numbers instead of the basic block  number in the output of CIL liveness module. I tried to edit this code in `liveness.ml` but I get an error every time:

```
let print_everything () =
 let d = IH.fold (fun i vs d -> 
d ++ num i ++ text ": " ++ LiveFlow.pretty () vs) 
  LiveFlow.stmtStartData nil in
 ignore(printf "%t" (fun () -> d))
```

This is the example output of liveness analysis of a C code:

```
1: byteinp(int ),ClrReqReceived(int ),
2: byteinp(int ),ClrReqReceived(int ),data(int ),ByteCount(int ),
3: byteinp(int ),ByteCount(int ),
```

I want line numbers of the C code at which the live variables are reported not the basic block number.